# how to filter a timestamp in Pig

Tags: hadoop, nosql, apache-pig

I have table with this schema:

```
(id: chararray, ts: long, data: chararray)
```

which ts stand for timestamp and store with UNIX time;

Because the data will update and the ts will be modified if update happen, id will not change. But all of this old record and new record will store in hdfs.

I just want to look at the latest data, so I write the pig code like this:

```
grp = GROUP table BY id;

rst = FOREACH grp {
    latest = FILTER table BY ts == MAX(table.ts);
    GENERATE latest.id AS id,
             latest.data AS data;
}
```

But seems that Pig code did not work, so do any one can give me a suggestion to make this code work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried order by `ts` in descending order?

```
LATEST = LIMIT (ORDER table BY ts desc) 1;
dump LATEST;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that's not working, but it also wouldn't be too hard to write a UDF to do this. Simply input the bag of tuples, loop over them, and return the tuple with biggest timestamp. Then you could just do:

```
grp = GROUP table BY id;
latest = FOREACH grp GENERATE my.udfs.LatestInBag(table);
```